# How to save a PySpark dataframe to the personal machine using Databricks?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe within the Databricks environment. I need to download this dataframe to my personal machine. This dataframe contains 10,000 rows. So try to do the following:

```
 df_test.coalesce(1).write.csv("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/df_test", header=True, mode='overwrite')
```

However, I'm not able to run the cell. The following error message appears:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
```

Could someone help me solve the problem?

Comment: please post the full exception - this information isn't enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn’t resolve the error, you can **try this alternate** to save your Pyspark dataframe to local machine as **csv** file.

**With `display(dataframe)`:**

Here I created a dataframe with 10,000 rows for your reference. With the `display()`, databricks allows to download the rows **up to 1 million**.

**Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
schema=StructType([ \
                   StructField("id",IntegerType(),True), \
                   StructField("firstname",StringType(),True) \
                   ])
data2=[(1,"Rakesh")]

for i in range(2,10000):
    data2.append((i,"Rakesh"))
df=spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
df.show(5)
display(df)
```

**Dataframe Creation:**

[image]

**`display(df):`**

In this output by default the display() shows 1000 rows and to download the total dataframe click on the **downarrow** and then click on **Download full results**.

[image]

Then, click on **re-execute and download**, now you can download the dataframe as csv file to your local machine.

[image]