# How to store SQL query results inthe excel or csv file?

Tags: azure-databricks

I am a newbie to data bricks and trying to write results into the excel/ CSV file using the below command but getting errors while executing.

I am using notebook to execute my SQL queries and now want to store store results in the CSV or excel file

```
 select * from tablename
 df.write.format("csv").save("/tmp/spark_output/datacsv")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `spark.table("mytable")` or `spark.sql("select * from mytable")` to store the sql table as dataframe after creating sql table.

**This is my sample SQL table:**

[image]

**Using `spark.table("mytable")`:**

[image]

**Using `spark.sql("select * from mytable)`:**

[image]

Then save the dataframe as csv using your code.

```
df1.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save("/tmp/spark_output/datacsv")
```

But in this approach the spark will create multiple csv's of our data like this.

[image]

To get a **single csv file** you can use `coalse(1)`, but if your data is small, you can use `pandas` here.

```
import pandas
pandas_converted=df.toPandas()
pandas_converted.to_csv("/dbfs/tmp/spark_output/mycsv.csv")
```

[image]

Make sure you add `/dbfs` at start of the file, otherwise it won't detect the path here.

**Single csv in the path:**

[image]

***SOURCES and REFERENCES:***

[Writing to a CSV file](https://analyticjeremy.github.io/Databricks_Examples/Write%20to%20a%20Single%20CSV%20File) by **Jeremy Peach(analyticjeremy)**.

Comment: Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input 'spark' expecting
== SQL ==
spark.table("SELECT * FROM customer").show()

Comment: In **spark.table("table_name")**, You have to give your sql table name i,e **customer** in your case. **select * from customer** this code should be given in spark.sql(). Please check my code above in both methods.

Comment: I have tried df =spark.sql('select * from  customer') df.show() but still its failing, I am using databricks notebook and language is SQL

Comment: spark.sql() and spark.table(), these are spark methods. Change the language of that particular cell to python by clicking on sql on right top of the cell as shown in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/notebooks-use#--mix-languages) and try the code. For creating sql table you can change it to sql in other cell.

Comment: By default for every cell, it will give SQL langauge as you have given when creating notebook. you can set whatever langauge you want for each cell as shown in that link. **For executing the above pyspark code it should be python language**.

Comment: How to store files at my local disk?

Comment: To store files at **dbfs** in databricks you can follow above. To save to local machine, after creating df dataframe use **display(df)** method and follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72912537/how-to-save-a-pyspark-dataframe-to-the-personal-machine-using-databricks/72914519#72914519).

Comment: I want to download it through code

Comment: Sorry to say, but its not to my knowledge, you can ask another question on it.